# Access Method of controller One in Controller 2 in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
    .controller('controller1',function($scope) {
    $scope.function1= function () {
    ---------------
    })
    .controller('controller2',function($scope) {
    $scope.function1= function () {
    //is it possible to access method form controller1 in controller2 like this
controller1.function();
    })
```

I'm beginner in angular JS please guide me to complete my code.

Comment: no you cannot access that in second controller but if you want something like this to share function b/w controllers create a angular service .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AngularJS you use Services for that kind of things.

Just create a Service with the Function you want to use multiple times:

```
.service('myService', function() {
    return function() {
        //your function1
    };
})
```

Then you use this Service as dependency:

```
.controller('controller2', [
    '$scope',
    'myService',//say you want the service as second param
    function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.function1 = function() {
            myService();//your function is here
        };
    }
])
```

And the same in the other controller:

```
.controller('controller1', [
    '$scope',
    'myService',
    function($scope,myService) {
        $scope.function1 = myService;//bind the service to the scope
    }
])
```

Comment: Moreover, if you need a service with multiple functions just return an object with function variables and call them like `myService.niceFunction()` from anywhere.

Comment: @DonJuwe of course, if he uses the other function also somewhere else, than it is smarter